# How can I set a height of an element relative to her parent and her sibling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  /*overflow: hidden; this only hides */
}

#sibling1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#sibling2{
  
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h3 id="sibling1">Variable Length Title</h3> 
  <div id="sibling2"> Variable lenght text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</div>
</div>
```

How can I get something like this?

Is there a way in css to model the sibling2 height based on the size of the parent and the height occupied by sibling1?

i.e sibling2.height = parent.height - sibling1.height

[image]

Comment: Why do you comment out `overflow: hidden`? Isn't that giving you what you're looking for? Change it to `overflow: scroll`, if you'd like to keep access to the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to check out the position property.
If you have text in a div container you could position that

element relative to the div container that it is inside using position: relative.

[W3Schools: Position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: You're right but with the position I can't control the height

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but according to your screen shot, you can add : `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` if you want scroll bar.

```css
#parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

#parent2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  overflow: auto; 
}

#sibling1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#sibling2{
  
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h3 id="sibling1">Variable Length Title</h3> 
  <div id="sibling2"> Variable lenght text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <h3 id="sibling1">Variable Length Title</h3> 
  <div id="sibling2"> Variable lenght text... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try #parent {height: 159px; } and look at what happen

Comment: @alessiovolpe Yes, 'i’ve tried. What are you trying to do ? Could you describe it precisely ?

Comment: I want to have the same result as your "#parent" but sibling1 must be fully visible on multiple rows if needed. Depending on the size of sibling1, the excess text of sibling2 must be truncated (most enriched with "...") and should not be visible in half text (eg with #parent{ height: 159px;} )

Comment: @alessiovolpe If you want to append '…', I think best solution is to use PHP in order to strip the string, or use javaScript.